# How to read specific cookie name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is how i write the cookie. My problem is how to read this specific cookie name. Thanks!

> HTML CODE:

```
<form name="myform" action="">  
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="indexValue" id="cookie"/>  
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="moviePath" id="path"/>  
</form>
```

> ```
> JAVASCRIPT CODE:
> ```

```
    function WriteCookie()
    {
        cookievalue= escape(document.myform.indexValue.value) + ";";
        path= escape(document.myform.moviePath.value) + ";";
        document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
        document.cookie="path=" + path;
    }
```

Comment: please correct your markup for better readablity. Use the preview and tooltips in the editor for help. Thanks. And Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your job super-easy, use pre-written tools like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/) or [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script). Parsing cookies can get tricky, and it's best to fall back on other folks' work for common tasks like this.

Here's the snippet from the QuirksMode article:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCookie(cName){
    if(document.cookie&&document.cookie.length){
           cStart = document.cookie.indexOf(cName + "=")
           if(cStart!=-1){
               //the index of value need to add cookie name's length and 1("=".length)
               cStart=cStart + cName.length + 1; 
               cEnd=document.cookie.indexOf(";",cStart);
               if(cEnd==-1){
                   cEnd=document.cookie.length;
               }
               return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cStart,cEnd));
          } 
     }
     return ""
}
```

the code based on [JavaScript Cookies w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)